# How can I find two missing parameters in r using lm() function?

Tags: r, lm, model-fitting, linearmodels

I was asking to find best fit values for two unknown parameters using the lm() function in r, I have used the lm function before but I am unsure of how to do this for unknown parameters?

I need to use the lm function on this formula

log⁡(C)~ log⁡(A)+ D log⁡(B)

Based off of this model

log(C)~ N(log⁡(A)+ D log⁡(B),σ^2 )

I already have the starting values for C and B in vectors, and I need to estimate A and D? I am not how to do this in r using the lm function.

Thank you!

Comment: Apply `summary` function on your model and you shall get your estimates.

Comment: Since I don't have a starting value for A and D I am getting errors. It says "non-numeric argument to mathematical function." When using nls you can input suggested starting values, but I don't believe you could do this with lm()?

Comment: Are C and B vectors? Then it is as simple as summary(lm(log(C) ~ log(B))). Make sure that C and B are of class "numeric" (e.g. by using a correct data import).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize the residual sum of squares, just use the lm function. Your output will contain an intercept and a coefficient associated with any predictor variables. Thus:

```
lm(log(C) ~ log(B), data = my_data)
```

You will predict log(C) as a linear combination of two parameters: the estimate of the "intercept" and the regression coefficient of log(B). For your purposes, this is log(A) and D respectively.

Comment: There is really no reason for using `optim`. `lm` works and is more efficient.

Comment: @Roland How would you use obtain log(b0) and log(b1) with lm()?

Comment: See my comment under the question. They are the intercept and slope of the `lm` model.

Comment: Yes @Roland but I think the user was implying that C and B were not known vectors. That was my interpretation of the question...

Comment: C and B are known vectors, I need to find the best-fit estimates for A and D.